# how to execute multiple animations simultaneously in mootools?

Tags: javascript, animation, mootools

I have two divs (say, divs with ids: div1 and div2) whose height I need to expand using Fx.Tween
And I want the animations to be simultaneous.

'#div1' 's style.height is to be changed from auto to 0.
'#div2' 's style.height is to be changed for current height to a new height calculated by a function called *calculateHeight()*

how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Mootools animations aren't blocking (animations in JS very rarely are!) so simply executing the two tweens sequentially will have the desired affect (as close as a human can perceive)

```
function go()
{
    $('div1').tween('height', 0);
    $('div2').tween('height', calculateHeight());
}

function calculateHeight()
{
    return 0; //or whatever
}
```

Comment: No I need to have these animations simultaneously because the second animation is kind of a corrective measure for the first one.

On doing it sequentially, is does not give a good user experience.

Comment: I think you need to explain more about what you're doing then, specifically how the two animations are related.

Comment: Give us some html and CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the wait:false option.
I'm not a programmer and mootools is easy but not as much to be so good at it but I remember reading some docs where it says you can control wether the second animation works as soon as the first one ends or simultaneously.

Chain Method: wait
Injects pauses between chained events.
Syntax

myClass.wait(duration);

Arguments
   1. duration - (integer) The duration (in milliseconds) to pause the chain stack; defaults to 500.

I think you should CHAIN the morphing and make it wait(0). But I'm not sure. Hope this helps.